# Error al tratat de asignar resultado a objeto

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, api

Cuando trato de asignar valores a un objeto desde un resultado desirializado (desde un API, JSon). Me sale el siguiente error:

```
Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path 'studentID'.
```

Aqui esta parte de mi codigo:

```
 resultJSonRequest = resultWebService;

IList<JToken> results = JasonResultList.ToList();

IList<Parameters> searchResults = new List<Parameters>();

searchResultsFromJason = searchResults;

foreach (JToken resultJAson in results)
{
    Parameters searchResult = resultJAson.ToObject<Parameters>();
    searchResults.Add(searchResult);

}
```

En donde se me cae es en la linea:

```
Parameters searchResult = resultJAson.ToObject<Parameters>();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi clase parameters:

```
[Serializable]
    class Parameters
    {
         public string studentID { get; set; }
         public string facultyID { get; set; }
    }
```

Saben como poder arregarlo?

Gracias

Comment: Hola. Puedes mostrar el de tu variable `results` ?tal vez no sea un json como esperas

Comment: Ídem. Es necesario cómo estás recibiendo la información en `results` para darnos una mejor idea.